# How can I convert my small program into a function for use in a project?

Tags: c++

I have the following small program to find the date a file was last modified. I need to turn it into a function so I could call the program in another function in a big project. I'm not sure how to turn my program into a function.

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <iomanip>

struct stat buf;

void convertEpochTime()
{
    std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = buf.st_mtime;
    std::time_t temp = time_date_stamp;
    std::tm* t = std::gmtime(&temp);
    std::cout << "[" << std::put_time(t, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p") << "]";
}

int main()
 {

     stat("testoutput.txt",&buf);
     convertEpochTime();

    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Does `main()` look like a function to you? What do you think would happen if you change `main()` name to something else?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like:

```
#include <a>
#include <b>
#include <c>

...

void ABC() {
    stat("testoutput.txt",&buf);

    // Migrated all the code of the function into a single function.
    // WARNING: If the function returns something, you need to assign
    //     the value into the variable.

    std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = buf.st_mtime;
    std::time_t temp = time_date_stamp;
    std::tm* t = std::gmtime(&temp);
    std::cout << "[" << std::put_time(t, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p") << "]";
}
.
.
.
// after everything >>>

int main(void) {
    A_very_big_program();
    more_functions();
    ...
    ABC();

    return 0;
}
```

Just rename the function name into something that must not be `main()` or any predefined ones, migrate the entire code (efficiently a void function which doesn't returns anything neither needs to assign anything into it, mentioned in the warning).